# PDEs boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have this boundary conditions question where $u(0,t)=0$, $u_x(\pi,t)=B$, $t>0$ So it asks what is the physical meaning of the boundary condition at $x=\pi$ in the three cases $B<0,B=0,B>0$.

Does it just means for $B=0$, there is no heat flowing, for $B<0$, the heat flow is decreasing and for $B>0$, the heat flow is increasing?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

[Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier.27s_law) establishes a connection between heat flux and temperature gradient

$$
{\bf q} = -k\nabla u
$$

Comment: Hmm can you explain. How does this connect to my question, don't I have the physical meaning correct here?

Comment: @user486026 Be careful with the sign in this equation

Comment: Which sign the - sign? So how does that help me determining the physical meaning. Can you give more hints?